# Katetov ordering on ideals on $\omega$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, order-theory, posets

Recall that a nonempty set ${\cal I}\subseteq {\cal P}(\omega)$ is a *(set) ideal* if

- $B\in{\cal I}$ and $A\subseteq B$ imply $A\in{\cal I}$, and
- $A,B \in {\cal I}$ implies $A\cup B\in {\cal I}$.

By $\text{Id}(\omega)$ we denote the set of all ideals on $\omega$. The *Katetov ordering* on $\text{Id}(\omega)$ is defined by $${\cal I} \leq_K {\cal J} :\Leftrightarrow (\exists f:\omega\to\omega)(\forall I\in{\cal I}) f^{-1}(I)\in J .$$

It is easy to see that $\leq_K$ is reflexive and transitive, but not anti-symmetric. Set ${\cal I}\simeq_K {\cal J}$ if ${\cal I}\leq_K{\cal J}$ and ${\cal J}\leq_K{\cal I}$.

**Questions.**

1) What are the cardinalities of the equivalence classes $[{\cal I}]_{\simeq_K}$ for ${\cal I}\in\text{Id}(\omega)$?

2) What is the cardinality of the poset $\text{Id}(\omega)/\simeq_K$?

Comment: Have you looked at the papers
"Katetov Order on Borel Ideals" by Hrusak 
and 
 "Some Structural Aspects of the Katetov Order
on Borel Ideals" by Guzman-Gonzalez, Meza-Alcantara?

They give some results which give lower bounds to your questions I think.

Comment: When restricted to maximal ideals, the Katetov ordering coincides with the Rudin-Keisler (RK) ordering. It is a matter of counting to see that there are  as many RK-classes of maximal ideals as there can be (i.e. $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$). This implies that the answer to 2) is $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

Comment: Thanks Ramiro, also for mentioning the Rudin-Keisler order! I would assume that the equivalence classes have size $2^{\aleph_0}$ as this is the cardinality of all functions $f:\omega\to\omega$, but maybe this reasoning is false. If it is correct, maybe you could put your comment in an answer?

Comment: It is not hard to see that classes restricted to maximal ideals have size at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ (could be less; for instance the class of the principal ideals is countable) for the reason you mentioned. I'm not so sure about the classes on the full set of ideals.